# Google Map not getting displayed

Tags: html, google-maps

I have made this google  custom map ,when i put on my browser it gets displayed but when i put on my web page .it shows a blank screen.
I can not find where am i going wrong.
 This is the map link:
https://mapsengine.google.com/map/edit?mid=zpzK8Kqu9aeI.kzlzNhKlCzB8

and this is what am doing in my web page :

```
<div class="image-display" id="displaylocate" style=" width:100%; height:100%;right:0%;top:0%;position:absolute;z-index:2;">                
                <iframe width="100%" height="87%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="position:absolute;left:0%;top:0%;" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://mapsengine.google.com/map/edit?mid=zpzK8Kqu9aeI.kzlzNhKlCzB8"></iframe><br /><small><a href="https://mapsengine.google.com/map/edit?mid=zpzK8Kqu9aeI.kzlzNhKlCzB8"style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a `display:none;` in that top level div. Not going to see much in there.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing edit with embed in the i frame tag helped my cause.

This is the final one

```
<iframe width="100%" height="87%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="position:absolute;left:0%;top:0%;" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://mapsengine.google.com/map/embed?mid=zpzK8Kqu9aeI.kzlzNhKlCzB8"></iframe><br /><small><a href="https://mapsengine.google.com/map/embed?mid=zpzK8Kqu9aeI.kzlzNhKlCzB8"style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>
```